# laravel 8 crude operation not showing

Tags: php, laravel

i have laravel connected
to database mysql
when i do insert/update i find it on the mysql table
but the page show data does not reflect the change
my page is products.

the web route:

```
<?php use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route; use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome'); });

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home'); 

Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);
```

---

the show index.blade.php  page :

```
@extends('products.layout')
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Laravel 8 CRUD Example from scratch - ItSolutionStuff.com</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('products.create') }}"> Create New Product</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif
   
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th width="280px">Action</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($products as $product)
        <tr>
            <td>hi</td>
            <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->detail }}</td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('products.destroy',$product->id) }}" method="POST">
   
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('products.show',$product->id) }}">Show</a>
    
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('products.edit',$product->id) }}">Edit</a>
   
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
      
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>     
@endsection
```

does any one can give me the reason why change not reflected

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K8k5.png)

Comment: how not working??

Comment: when i run first time it show data, but when i do change not showing, but show old data, next day i run it show the new data , after operation not show at moment

Comment: if i run on localhost i show the update
when i upload to real server, not showing

Comment: i post image from real server to show the problem only

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, after updating product, try to do:

```
return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: thanks 
but after update already back : 

 return redirect()->route('products.index')
                 ->with('success','Product updated successfully');